# Change the data type of a field in multiple shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fields-attributes

Is there a way I can change the data type of a field (possibly using the python window). I have about 25 shapefiles which are all named differently, but the name of the fields I want to change from text to double are the same.

Comment: You can do it (manually) in ArcCatalog, I believe -- ref. [Modifying field properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000100000000)

Comment: I thought so too!

http://i.imgur.com/14nKO9v.png

Comment: "If the field contains data, you cannot change data types that would lead to loss of data. For example, you cannot change a long integer or float to a short integer, or change a blob to a text."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is no way to change a field type.  Single biggest complaint of all time on the ideas site, ignored by Esri for over a decade.  If they ever did it they would only support it in a geodatabase, never a shapefile (a dead end format).  Access could do it if this was a Personal geodatabase and probably SDE databases could do it directly.

You have to create a new double field and calculate the string values into it in each table.  Python could do that process in a loop if the files are in the same directory.

Comment: I've just re-exported my raw data, changed field types in MapInfo then translated it back into a shapefile